# GridGain cache data compression factor (how to find out ?)

Tags: caching, compression, storage, gridgain

I am looking to see how efficient data storage is with GridGain's cache. ie. if I load 1TB of data into the cache do it take 1TB of space? Most of the data is going to be repetitive with certain fields being the same, ie. Browser="Chrome" for example, so I am hoping to see how GridGain makes use of this repetition

I've looked around and found http://gridgain.com/columnar-vs-key-value-storage-models/ but it doesn't really give solid statistics per se, but does foreshadow a short coming, as it notes there is a 'lack of ' compression - but I wanted to see if this means that x TB of data in = x TB of RAM gone and I wanted to understand how I can view this myself (perhaps through ggvisor?)

Goal: Look at the cluster and see I have Y GB of available RAM. Load X units of data into the cache via GridDataLoader. Look at the cluster and see I have Y' GB of available RAM. So the compression can be calculated through X : (Y - Y')

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GridGain does not have data compression, but if you use `Externalizable` objects, primitive types, or Strings, the format will be fairly compact. You can also try to use any kind of compaction on the client side and store compacted byte arrays in cache.

Also, try setting `GridCacheConfiguration.setStoreValueBytes(false)` and see if it saves space.

Comment: what method would you suggest to view the amount of data used vs amount of data stored? I am currently look at the heap memory used (delta) before and after I store X amount of data. I am thinking of writing a script to simply (1) compute heap size used (2) load X amount of data into the cluster (3) compute heap size prime. But I would need to do this for every node so it sounds a bit messy. Any suggestions?

Comment: @s'-wh Another approach will be to look at the memory footprint in a profiler, such as VisualVM.